# C++: hide method from children

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, information-hiding

I have a class called `transform`, and its child classes, `translation`, `rotation` and `scaling`, which are supposed to apply transformations on a triangle.

Each of the child classes overrides the `apply_transform()` method:

```
class transform
{
protected:
    virtual triangle apply_transform(const triangle&) const = 0;
public:
    static triangle apply_transforms(const triangle&, const std::initializer_list<const transform*>&);
};

class scaling : public transform
{
...
public:
    triangle apply_transform(const triangle&) const override;
};

//same for rotation and translation
```

I also have a function called `apply_transforms`, which should be accessible to the outside world, and I use it to apply multiple transformations. I pass it a list of `transform*` to enable polymorphism.

The only issue I have is that now, the child classes are also aware of this method. This is bothering me since a child class shouldn't be able to apply all of the other transformations.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Well, you either have the function visible to the outside world (which includes the derived classes) or you hide it to everybody.

Comment: Could apply_transforms be public static on the triangle class?

Comment: I'd suggest that you simply stop being bothered by this. Are you bothered that my string class, which has nothing to do with geometry, can also have access to this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `apply_transforms` a non-member function that is not included into header files required by classes implementing `transform`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest changing how you view transforms a little bit.

1. Make `transform` a class such that it does not need other classes to be derived from it. All the data needed to transform a point can be kept in this class.
2. Add functions that construct scaling transform, translation transform, and rotational transform.
3. Add functions to multiply transforms, and multiply a transform and a point. These can be building blocks for transforming other shapes.
4. Add functions for transforming other shapes as needed.

---

In a skeletal form,

```
class transform { ... };
class position { ... };

// tag structs
struct rotation_about_x {};
struct rotation_about_y {};
struct rotation_about_z {};

// Functions to construct transforms
transform construct_scale_transform(double scale_factor) { ... };
transform construct_translation_transform(position pos) { ... };
transform construct_rotation_transform(double angle, rotation_about_x tag) { ... };
transform construct_rotation_transform(double angle, rotation_about_y tag) { ... };
transform construct_rotation_transform(double angle, rotation_about_z tag) { ... };

// Function to transform a point.
position operator*(transform const& t, position const& p) { ... }

// Function to multiply transforms.
transform operator*(transform const& t1, transform const& t2) { ... }


// Functions to apply transforms to other objects.
triangle operator*(transform const& tr, triangle const& t) { ... }
...
```

Usage:

```
transform t1 = construct_rotation_transform(10, rotation_about_x{});
transform t2 = construct_translation_transform({20, 10, 0});

position p1{100, 200, 30};
position p2 = t1*t2*p1;

triangle tr1{ ... }
triangle tr2 = t1*t2*tr1;
```

If you are going to use the same combined transform multiple times, compute the combined transform first and use it for all transforms.

```
transform t1 = construct_rotation_transform(10, rotation_about_x{});
transform t2 = construct_rotation_transform(5, rotation_about_y{});
transform t3 = construct_translation_transform({20, 10, 0});
tranform tc = t1 * t2 * t3;

position p1{100, 200, 30};
position p2 = tc*p1;

triangle tr1{ ... }
triangle tr2 = tc*tr1;
```

Comment: But note that the "natural" syntax using `*` is always left-to-right associative in C++, which can be inefficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication

Comment: @BenVoigt, good point. Fortunately, you can compute a combined transform and use it as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that since your `apply_transforms(...)` method is public, it is as such available to all potential callers. Considering this, you cannot, nor should you, prevent the child classes from being able to see these methods.

If you know that your method will be called from specific classes, you can make your method private and declare those calling classes as friends.

Otherwise, encapsulate the method in a different class to prevent child classes of `transform` from containing it.